# Could someone explain how this function works in laymans terms?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

So I know what this code is doing, it is checking to see if the code is "uniform" for instance `a,a,a,a,a,a` or `1,1,1,1,1,1` and if it's not it is returning a false statement. However I'm not exactly sure how this equation is working. Mostly I'm confused by the `array[0]` and why the variable is `i = 1`. Could someone walk me through exactly what is happening here and why this works?

```
function isUniform(arr){
    var first = arr[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] !== first){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It would help greatly if you would post how you think it works. We can only guess what your skill level is.

Comment: So I'm reading it that the first variable array is zero, the var in the for statement is i = 1, anything less than the length of the array, add 1 to it. If that array doesn't equal 0 then return false. Which is why I'm confused, shouldn't it want it to equal itself in order to return a true?

Comment: Another way to write it is: `var first = arr[0]; return arr.every(val => val === first);`

Comment: `arr[0]` refers to the first element in array. If an array has 4 elements, they will be `arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]`.

Comment: You seem confused by the concept of an array.  If you think of a variable as a box with a name that can hold a value, then an array is named row of such boxes, each box with a number.  When you want to put a value in, or look at the value in one of those boxes, you put the number of the box in square-brackets after the name as in `arr[0]` or `arr[3]`.  Some (dumb) languages start numbering the boxes at one (1,2,3,...), JavaScript starts at zero (0,1,2,...)

Comment: @4castle it will probably be some time before they are ready for that approach...

Comment: @JohnHascall IMHO `for` loops are way more complicated than that approach

Comment: @4castle It is to you now, but which did you learn first when a programming beginner?

Comment: @JohnHascall I was experienced with C-like languages before I ever learned JS, so I suppose I couldn't know. All I remember is that it took me a long time to understand `for` loops, and only a small amount of time to understand functions.

Comment: I'm coming from HTML and CSS so this is all new to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays in JavaScript are zero-based. Therefore the line

```
var first = arr[0]
```

represents the first element of the `arr` argument passed into the array. It never changes.

The loop

```
for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
```

iterates over all but the first element array, starting at the second element (`arr[1]`) to the final element. Along the way the statement `if(arr[i] !== first)` simply compares each array element (except for the first one), to the first array element being stored in `first`. If any one doesn't match, false is returned, else true is returned. If the input array was `[1,2,3,4,5]`, then `arr[0]=1, arr[1]=2, arr[2]=3...` and the value of the first array element (and the variable `first`) would be `1`, and the loop would iterate over the rest of the array values (`2, 3, 4, and 5`). It would therefore return false on the first iteration as 1 is not equal to 2.

There's nothing fancy or exceptional about this function as all it does is walk down the values of an array, comparing elements.

Comment: Ok so I think I follow a little but maybe not.

So lets say my array is [3,3,3,3,3,2]

The section arr[0] is actually just storing the number 3 right?

So the section that would be confusing still would be the loop part. Are we changing that 3 to a 1 and then making sure that 1 is less than the array length 1+1?

Comment: You're correct that `arr[0]` is 3. The `0` refers to the first element of the array. The loop is independent of the array. It's just counting from 1 to the end of the array. Using your example in the comment, it would count 1,2,3,4 and 5. So when the loop first runs, it compares `arr[1]` which is the second value in the array (the indices of arrays begin at zero) and is also 3. And on and on until the end of the array. The `i` variable in the loop is just there to serve as a counter. It gets incremented from 1 to 5 so that we can check each element of the array.

Comment: Again using your example in the comment, `arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], and arr[4]` all contain the same value of `3`. It's the last array element `arr[5]` which contains `2`. The loop uses `i` to select the array element. `i` goes from 1 to 5.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to get this, so basically that equation is just to tell the computer to keep moving on to the next array and check that against the arr[0]?

Comment: Right. Don't think of it as an equation. Think of it as a statement with three parts that just creates a loop. All `for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)` means is set a variable `i` to equal `1`. The second part is our check. It says is `i` less than the length of the array (which is 6)? If so, keep going.The last part increments `i` by 1.

Comment: The loop seems to be tripping you up a bit. Have a look at some more info about for loops at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Cool, thanks for the help, I will read the MDN that you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Have given comments in the code using `//` hope it helps

```
function isUniform(arr){
    var first = arr[0]; //storing the first value in the array in variable 'first'
   //arr.length gives the number of elements in the array
   //looping between numbers 1 and the end of the length of array (array.length)
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){ 
        if(arr[i] !== first){ //checking if current value (arr[i]) is equal to first value
            return false;//if it is not equal returning false and return ends the loop and function
        }
          //if all the values are equal the above if condition never runs
    }
    //if above if condition never runs, this statement runs and returns true
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: This is helping, I guess the for statement is still confusing though. I'm reading it like a math equation. I have to think of it as moving the check point one down each time correct? So since 0 has already been checked, it starts with 1, checks it against the arr[0] number and if it is the same moves to the next number?

Comment: The `for` statement is just a shorthand.  `for ( A; B; C ) { body }` is the mostly the same as: `A; while (B) { body; C }`

Comment: It is a common mistake to see `i = 1` and think that is math.  What this is saying is put the value `1` in the "box" (variable) named `i`.  It's proper name is an *assignment statement" -- the value of the variable is assigned.  In some other languages the assignment operator is not `=` but something that looks more like an arrow, as in  `i <- 1` or `i := 1` and that seems clearer.

Answer (score 0):

length in javascript is not 0 based. So the following array has a length of 4.

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Arrays on the other hand are 0 based, so to get the 4th element of this array you would do arr[3] which would equal 4. The number inside the square braces represents the position in the array, not the value.

Answer (score 0):

First, we stores the first element of the array into the variable `first`. and then we start looping over the rest of the array's elements (that's why `i` starts with `1` because there is no need to compare an element with itself). If the current element `arr[i]` is different from the first element `first` (means the array is not uniform), the function return `false` (when a function return it will be exited immediately so there will be no more comparing with other elements of the array). If we loop over all the elements of the array and we came out of the loop then we didn't find any different values, so the array is uniform thus we return `true` and exit the function.